# display the number of characters in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, document, jtextarea

I am looking for a example to display the number of characters the user has already input in Java JTextArea. I want to have a limit number of characters (255) in JTextArea.

```
JTextArea kommentarArea = new JTextArea(11, 10);
kommentarArea.setLineWrap(true);
kommentarArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);

AbstractDocument pDoc = (AbstractDocument) kommentarArea.getDocument();
pDoc.setDocumentFilter(new DocumentSizeFilter(MAXCOMMENTCHARS));
int option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, kommentarArea, "Bitte geben Sie einen   Kommentar ein", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, imexIcon, null, null);
if (option == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION && kommentarArea.getDocument().getLength() <= MAXCOMMENTCHARS)
    return kommentarArea.getText();
else if (kommentarArea.getDocument().getLength() > MAXCOMMENTCHARS) {
    throw new CommentTooLongException("Die Länge der Kommentare ist länger als 255 Zeichern");
} else {
    LOGGER.info("Versenden der Datei wurde abbrechen");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

I use the DocumentSizeFilter from Java tutorial. However, I want to have a text label in this dialog so that user can see how many characters has been input in the JTextArea

Comment: What have you tried already, what exactly is not working as expected? Give us some code that you have written already, or do you just want someone to develop the solution for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can attach a listener (listen a `TextEven` or `DocumentEvent`) and when the text is too long, you send a warning to the user.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a DocumentListener to listen for changes to the textarea:

```
kommentarArea.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener {
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent event) {
        if (kommentarArea.getDocument().getLength() > 255) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Die Länge der Kommentare ist länger als 255 Zeichern");
        }
    }

    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        if (kommentarArea.getDocument().getLength() > 255) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Die Länge der Kommentare ist länger als 255 Zeichern");
        }
    }

    public void changeUpdate(DocumentEvent event) {
        if (kommentarArea.getDocument().getLength() > 255) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Die Länge der Kommentare ist länger als 255 Zeichern");
        }
    }
});
```